# Using commuting operators to express states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, eigenvalue, observables

I read that it is natural to use commuting operators to express physical state-vectors in QM. For example, if the energy momentum four vector operators all commute, it is natural to express state-vectors in terms of eigenvectors of the four-momentum.

I know that commuting operators share common eigenstates, but why is it *natural* to express states in terms of eigenstates of commuting operators? What is the usefulness in doing so?

Comment: I wonder, what is the alternative to eigenstates of commuting operators?

Comment: @Pavlo.B. I was thinking of labeling the eigenstates with a single operator instead of multiple commuting operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree a little bit with the way the premise of this question is stated. Let me say how I think of it.

It is natural to express states as a superposition of eigenstates of *observables.* The reason is that then we can associate a physical meaning to each basis state. In the position representation (assuming one particle), each basis state corresponds to measuring the particle at a particular location. In the momentum representation, each eigenstate corresponds to measuring the particle with a particular momentum. And so on.

In fact I think underlies is a logically crucial step in setting up a quantum mechanical model -- choosing the operators you identify as "observables" connects the Hilbert space to the real world. While you *can* choose a basis that is not aligned with an observable operator even approximately, it is such an unnatural thing to do that I don't think I've ever seen it done.

However often choosing one observable and using its eigenstates to define a basis is not enough. For one thing, from a physics point of view, we obviously want to know as much as we can about the system, and so using a *complete set of commuting observables* ensures we can identify all the quantities that can be observed in a given basis state. More subtly, because a given observable can have a degenerate spectrum, using a complete set of commuting observables lets us assign a unique label to each state. Because those labels are the eigenvalues of observables, each eigenstate corresponds to a different experimentally possible outcome.

Tl;dr: What we really want is to express the state in terms of eigenstates of *observable* operators, as opposed to some random basis. Once we know we want this, it is natural to look for a *complete set of observables* so that we can fully characterize the states in terms of observable outcomes.

Comment: That means that if $[A,B]=0$, we can label the eigenstates with $|a,b \rangle$ where $a$ and $b$ are the eigenvalues. The eigenstates $|a,b\rangle$ with same values of $a$ and different values of $b$ are degenerate eigenstates of operator $A$. Is that correct?

Comment: @TaeNyFan Yes, exactly